# How to draw only certain parts of an array filled with vertex data

Tags: c++, opengl

**CONTEXT:**

I am trying to create an open world nature-like scene in openGL. An array `terrainVertices` of length `3*NUM_OF_VERTICES` contains the vertex data for the terrain, which is a noise generated heightmap. Each vertex has `x,y,z` coordinates, and based on the value of `y` a certain color is assigned to the vertex, producing a somewhat smooth transition between deep waters and mountain peaks.

**PROBLEM:**

The lakes are formed when a neighbourhood of vertices has a y value, such that `y<0`. The colouring is performed as expected, however the result is not realistic. It looks like a blue pit:

[image]

The way I decided to tackle this issue is by creating a layer of vertices, that appear over the lake, having `y=0` and a light blue color with low alpha value, thus creating the illusion of a surface, beneath which lies the actual lake.

The `terrainVertices` array is indexed by an element array `elements[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS]`. I iterate over the element array and try to find triplets of indices, that correspond to vertices with `y<0`. I gather every triplet that matches this condition in a vector, then create a new vertex array object, with the same vertex data as the terrain, but with the new element buffer object I just described. The vertices that are "underwater" have their y value replaced by `0`, so as to stick to the surface of the lake.

Here's the code I used to accomplish this:

```
std::vector<GLuint> waterElementsV;

//iterating over every triangle
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS / 3; i++) {

    //accessing each vertex based on its index from the element array
    //checking if its height is lower than zero
    //elements[3*i+0, +1, +2] represents the indices for a triangle
    //terrainVertices[index + 1] represents the height of the vertex
    if (terrainVertices[3 * (elements[3 * i]) + 1] < 0 &&
        terrainVertices[3 * (elements[3 * i + 1]) + 1] < 0 &&
        terrainVertices[3 * (elements[3 * i + 2]) + 1] < 0) {


        //since its a valid triangle, add its indices in the elements array.
        waterElementsV.push_back(elements[3 * i]);
        waterElementsV.push_back(elements[3 * i + 1]);
        waterElementsV.push_back(elements[3 * i + 2]);

    }

}


//iterating through the terrain vertices, and setting
//each appropriate vertex's y value to water surface level y = 0
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < waterElementsV.size(); i++) {

    currentIndex = waterElementsV[i];

    terrainVertices[3 * currentIndex + 1] = 0;

}

//get the vector's underlying array
waterElements = waterElementsV.data();


glGenVertexArrays(1, &waterVAO);
glBindVertexArray(waterVAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &waterVerticesVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, waterVerticesVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_OF_VERTICES, terrainVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


glGenBuffers(1, &waterEBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, waterEBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(waterElements), waterElements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The shaders are very simple, as I only need to assign a position and a colour. No world view projection matrices are used, because every object is drawn relative to the terrain anyway.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The result is exactly the same as in the above picture. I've been picking my brain about what is going on but I cannot seem to figure it out... Note that the lakes are spread out at random places, and are not necessarily adjacent to each other.

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated :)